# Ansible gce module: create instance with customize disk size

Tags: python, ansible, google-compute-engine

I want to create google compute instance with ansible gce module with 100 GB disk. But there is no configuration in gce module for set the disk size of the instance in gce module.

I know we can work around by using gce_pd module to create the disk then attach to new instance, but is there any proper way to do it?

It so simple to support it because the lib cloud lib already support this param.

Comment: You can use "size_gb:100 ". more information in this article: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/gce_pd_module.html

Comment: I want to create disk associate with new instance http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/gce_module.html not using gce_pd module. Now I'm using gce_pd as a solution but it make my code look dirty.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be possible directly, but the `gce` module uses the first item in `disks` as the boot image (see [code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/7f55c9fc8eb05c525adeea69043620a7b3023ac4/cloud/google/gce.py#L440)).

So you can create a customized boot disk as follows:

```
- name: Create custom boot disk
  gce_pd:
    name: "{{ instance_name }}"
    image: "{{ instance_image }}"
    size_gb: "{{ disk_size }}"
    zone: "{{ zone  }"

- name: Launch instance with custom boot disk
  gce:
    name: "{{ instance_name }}"
    image: "{{ instance_image }}"
    zone: "{{ zone }}"
    disks:
      - name: "{{ instance_name }}"
        mode: READ_WRITE
```